# Youtube Webcam Widget - Grabbing VideoID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, youtube-api, webcam, redactor

For my Rails application, I am have projects where users can post updates via Redactor Rails.  I have a controller and model for `BLOGPOSTS` made for each project.  Right now, they can embed video with this rich text editor fine. But, I am exploring option of adding an option to allow users to directly webcam record with youtube on my site and have it uploaded to youtube and posted as a BLOGPOST for the project. Blogposts are currently saved in the blogupdates table as `t.text     "content"`.

I referenced documentation here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget

****Question: When I added the youtube upload widget, it shows the webcam. I then record, and after, it just generates the uploaded video for playback.  But is there a way I can grab the video ID and have it save as a "BLOGPOST" `content` with the set  embed html automatically after the video is recorded?**

So I added the following to each project page:

**view/projects/show.html.erb**

```
<script>
  // 2. Asynchronously load the Upload Widget and Player API code.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. Define global variables for the widget and the player.
  //    The function loads the widget after the JavaScript code
  //    has downloaded and defines event handlers for callback
  //    notifications related to the widget.
  var widget;
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    widget = new YT.UploadWidget('widget', {
      width: 500,
      events: {
        'onUploadSuccess': onUploadSuccess,
        'onProcessingComplete': onProcessingComplete
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. This function is called when a video has been successfully uploaded.
  function onUploadSuccess(event) {
    alert('Video ID ' + event.data.videoId + ' was uploaded and is currently being processed.');
  }

  // 5. This function is called when a video has been successfully
  //    processed.
  function onProcessingComplete(event) {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: 390,
      width: 640,
      videoId: event.data.videoId,
      events: {}
    });

  }
</script>
<div class = "container">
  <div id="widget"></div>
  <div id="player"></div>
</div>
```

In addition, each page shows the Redactor Rails form:

```
<%= form_for([@project, @project.blogposts.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, label: "Blog Posts", :class => "redactor", %>
  </div>

  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Add Blog Post", :class => "btn btn-header" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**blogposts_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

  params[:blogpost][:content] = sanitize_redactor(params[:blogpost][:content])

  @blogpost = @project.blogposts.create!(params[:blogpost])

  if @blogpost.save
    redirect_to blogs_project_path(@project), notice: "Blog entry created."
  end   
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "blogposts", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "project_id"
  t.text     "content"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that blogging platform, so my answer is not going to specific to that.

In general, there are two ways to embed a video using the YouTube iframe player. One is to add the embed programmatically, using the `YT.Player` constructor to replace an existing element in your page's DOM. That's what you're doing in the code you provided.

The other way is to explicitly include an `<iframe>` with the appropriate properties in your page's DOM. Chances are this will follow a standard template and the other thing that will need to vary is the video id. An example `<iframe>` tag to load in an embedded player for `VIDEO_ID` is

```
<iframe type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

So if you wanted to save some HTML (to a datastore or wherever) that contained a YouTube embed, the best way to do it would be to include that `<iframe>` tag in the HTML, with the correct `VIDEO_ID` value corresponding to the newly uploaded video.